# Print multiple files on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get the code to print multiple pages based off the loop value in qtytxt. The output displays and prints out the first output. How can I fix the code to where it prompts me to print the others values?

```
  report = "";
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById("qtytxt").value; i++) {
        report += "ID: " + document.getElementById("generateidtxt").value + "-" + (i + 1) + "<br>";
        document.open();
        document.clear();
        document.write(report);
        document.close();
        window.print();
```

For example, If the value in qtytxt was 3, I want it to prompt me to print out 3 times. With a new "-x" value for each.

Comment: What is exactly your problem. What are the results you get?

Comment: I want the loop to prompt me to print multiple times based off the value in qtytxt. The loop produces a id number with an addition of a "-x" number from 1 to whatever value was put into qtytxt. For example if the number was 3, I want it to prompt to print for id-1, then ask me to print again with a new label id-2, and then again for id-3.

Comment: yes, but what is the result of your code?

Comment: the window.print() is inside the loop, so I wanted it to prompt me multiple times, but it only prompts me once and the loop stops.

Comment: to identify where the problem comes, you should use something la firebug (with firefox), and put breakpoints inside your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Due javascript security reasons they will not allow to print child windows. But  you might try something like following link.

[Printing multiple PDF files using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187400/printing-multiple-pdf-files-using-javascript)