# TCPDF and FPDI with multiple pages

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

This looks like the simplest thing but I can't get it to work.

I need to add text to the first page of a multi-page pdf (could be any number of pages)

Using this code on a two page pdf (without the for loop, just using $pdf->importPage(2)) I end up with two pages but the second page is a repeat of page one. The text is written on the first page only which is good but I need all pages included in the output pdf. Here is my code

```
// Original file with multiple pages 
$fullPathToFile = 'full/path/to/file.pdf';

class PDF extends FPDI {

    var $_tplIdx;

    function Header() {

        global $fullPathToFile;

        if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {

            $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
            $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);

        }
        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);

    }

    function Footer() {}

}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);


// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// The new content
$pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "B", 14);
$pdf->Text(10,10,'Some text here');

// How to get the number of pages of original pdf???
// $numPages = $pdf->getNumPages(???);

// Carry on adding all remaining pages starting from page 2
for($i=2;$i<=$numPages;$i++) {
    // Add another page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    // Do I need to declare the source file here?
    // $pdf->setSourceFile($fullPathToWD);
    $pdf->importPage($i);
}

// Output the file as forced download
$pdf->Output('theNewFile.pdf', 'D');
```

**Links to docs**

TCPDF Classes
http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a5171e20b366b74523709d84c349c1ced

FPDI Classes
http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/

FPDF_TPL Classes
http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdf-tpl/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved my problem...

```
// Original file with multiple pages 
$fullPathToFile = 'full/path/to/file.pdf';

class PDF extends FPDI {

    var $_tplIdx;

    function Header() {

        global $fullPathToFile;

        if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {

            // THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
            $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
            $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);

        }
        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);

    }

    function Footer() {}

}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);


// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// The new content
$pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "B", 14);
$pdf->Text(10,10,'Some text here');

// THIS PUTS THE REMAINDER OF THE PAGES IN
if($pdf->numPages>1) {
    for($i=2;$i<=$pdf->numPages;$i++) {
        $pdf->endPage();
        $pdf->_tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
        $pdf->AddPage();
    }
}

// Output the file as forced download
$pdf->Output('theNewFile.pdf', 'D');
```

You get the number of pages by adding the first part of this line

```
$this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
```

And see the second last block of code - the for loop adds the remainder of the pages.

Don't know if this is how it should be done? I read in a few places that it wasn't even possible to achieve this, also the code is not supplied in the docs. However, this works, hope it helps someone.

Comment: You could also just have put the `useTemplate` in that `for` loop instead of extending the class, that would probably make the for loop more intuitive (i.e. get data (`importPage`), print data (`useTemplate`)). But good question/answer nevertheless, it inspired me to solve my own issue!

Comment: The method `$pdf->endPage()` is no longer present.

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this a little and tried to come up with simplest way to add some text to the last page of a multi-page document.  Here is the very simple code that worked for me:

```
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdf/fpdi.php');
$pdf = new FPDI();
$fullPathToPDF = '/usr/local/common/my.pdf';
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($fullPathToPDF);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
    $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($i);
}
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetXY(110, 225);
$pdf->Write(8, 'A complete document imported with FPDI');
$pdf->Output($fullPathToPDF);
```

Just change the full path to file to a location where you have a multi-page PDF.

Comment: `$pdf->Output('F', $path)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
...
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10);
foreach($array as $item)
{
  $pdf->AddPage(); //add new page for new item
  $txt = some_long_long_text;
  $pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true);
  $pdf->endPage(); //do end of page
  $pdf->lastPage(); //set cursor at last page, because autopagebreak not do it
}
```

In example, you have 10 pupils in array, and you need create resume for each. In exam, one resume have 3 pages. So in out u get pdf with 30 pages, with correct text.
SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10), not set cursor at last page, so you need to do it manually with function `$pdf->lastPage();`

Answer (score 0):

that code wont work, try this:

```
$pdf = new PDI();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile('zzz.pdf');
$pdf->numPages = $pdf->setSourceFile('zzz.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 20, 200);
    if($pdf->numPages>1) {
for($i=2;$i<=$pdf->numPages;$i++) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 20, 200);
}
}
```