# PHP code to read and delete page from pdf file

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf, fpdi

I have a system that generates PDF files, each file consists of two pages. For some reason I need to write a PHP code which can delete the second page from each PDF file. Herer is what I've done and what was the results:

1- I used TCPDF library to write the folowing code:

```
require_once('TCPDF-master/examples/tcpdf_include.php');
require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf_import.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF_IMPORT( 'test.pdf' );
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->deletePage(2);
$pdf->Output('test_output.pdf', 'I');
```

The result: Blank one page PDF file. In other words, the content from the original file was not available in the new file

2- I used FPDF and FPDI libraries to read only one page from the original file.

```
require_once('FPDF-master/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI-1.6.1/fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('test.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 90);

$pdf->Output();
```

The result is this error message:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This document (test.pdf)
>   probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the
>   free parser shipped with FPDI. (See
>   https://www.setasign.com/fpdi-pdf-parser for more details)' in
>   C:\wamp\www\FPDI-1.6.1\pdf_parser.php on line 322

Anybody knows how to help please??

Comment: Did you try the parsers in that link? Maybe you need the commercial addon to be able to open your source file.

Comment: The problem that it's quite expensive, so I can't use it, I'm searching for free solution

Comment: Take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546275/tcpdf-and-fpdi-with-multiple-pages, you can modified for your needs

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a tool like pdftk. You can invoke it from PHP if you prefer. Command line below to extract a page.

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1 output out.pdf
```