# Resize PDF file with TCPDF and FPDI

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdi

im using TCPDF and FPDI to import existing pdf file and write text on it.

i want to resize the pdf file to A4 properties W:595.2 H:8870.89

the reason i want to change the size, is because i want to place text with position that matches the page's pixels.

here is my code (Taken from here: [TCPDF and FPDI with multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546275/tcpdf-and-fpdi-with-multiple-pages))

```
// Original file with multiple pages 
$fullPathToFile = '../documents/test5.pdf';

class PDF extends Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi {

    var $_tplIdx;

    function Header() {

        global $fullPathToFile;

        if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {

            // THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE NUMBER OF PAGES
            $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
            $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);

        }
        $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);

    }

    function Footer() {}

}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF('P','pt');
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);



// set some language dependent data:
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'he';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 12);



// add a page
$pdf->AddPage(); 


$htmlpersian = 'hello world';
$pdf->SetXY(40, 255);
$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlpersian, true, 0, true, 0);


// THIS PUTS THE REMAINDER OF THE PAGES IN
if($pdf->numPages>1) {
    for($i=2;$i<=$pdf->numPages;$i++) {
        $pdf->endPage();
        $pdf->_tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
        $pdf->AddPage(); 
    }
}

// Output the file as forced download
$pdf->Output('theNewFile.pdf', 'I');
```

thanks for the helpers