# How to merge multiple pdfs into one without writing the response into a new file

Tags: php, shell, pdf, curl

I have been going though examples of merging multiple pdfs into one after fetching them with a curl response.
But, all the examples requires the pdf response to be written into a pdf file and then pass them to fdpi or some other lib to merge them.
I want to skip the file writing operation and want to pass the curl response directly to the fdpi library.
What can be the solution to this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new PDF by Merging PDF documents using TCPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630016/creating-a-new-pdf-by-merging-pdf-documents-using-tcpdf)

Comment: no this is not a duplicate, as my question asks to merge the pdfs without writing the response into a new file

Comment: tcpf allows you to do this and then keep the string in memory for whatever use, it does not dictate you write a new file

Comment: can you provide an example without the $pdf->setSourceFile, as in the link that you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPDI depends on filesystem functions such as fseek() or fread() and requires to use a stream wrapper as described [here](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/miscellaneous/using-a-pdf-from-a-php-variable-instead-of-a-file/#question-76), if you want to import a PDF from a variable.

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile(VarStream::createReference($yourCurlResponse));
```